# networked-aframe assign different position to new user

Tags: javascript, multiplayer, aframe

I have a problem in my multiplayer A-Frame environment that I set up with networked-aframe.

I want the first three users that connect to have a different spawn location and any additional user to spawn at the third location, but I can't get it to work. Here's what I have so far in Html:

```
 <a-entity id="player" 
networked="template:#avatar-template;showLocalTemplate:true;" 
camera 
positioner=""
wasd-controls 
look-controls>
<a-cursor></a-cursor>  
</a-entity>
```

And here is the JS Component for it:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('positioner', {
init: function() {

        var el = this.el,
            counter = 0;

        if (counter == 0) {
            el.setAttribute('position', {x:-16,  y:6,  z:-10});
            counter++;
        }
        else if(counter == 1) {
            el.setAttribute('position', {x:-10,  y:6,  z:-10});
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            el.setAttribute('position', {x:-5,  y:6,  z:-10});
            counter++;
        }
}
});
```

I found out that I have to sync additional components which I am doing like this:

```
var avatarSchema = {
template: '#avatar-template',
components: [
'positioner',
'position',
'rotation',
'scale',
{
  selector: '.head',
  component: 'material'
},
{
  selector: '.hairs',
  component: 'show-child'
}


]
};
       NAF.schemas.add(avatarSchema);
```

It's a big project so there's a lot more code. If you need anything else like the scene setup or the avatar setup let me know and I will add it.

Comment: imo the positioner will fire once for each player so the counter will be always 0. Do You know how to get the player list ? You could change the location depending which player You are when joined

Comment: That sounds reasonable. No I don't know how to get the player list, how do I?

Comment: thats why i asked, i have no clue :D even put it in the issues: https://github.com/haydenjameslee/networked-aframe/issues/19 . If i get any response I'll let You know. If You find out a way, please post it as an anwser

Comment: Ah I see :D Alright, will do and thanks!

Comment: I think I got something

Comment: Can you check how many people are currently connected and use that as a counter? You might have to dig around NAF or ask Hayden on how to do that. A hack would be to query selector how many players are in the scene and use that as a counter.

Comment: No, that's been the problem to it. I have tried your hack and it WORKS for now thanks Kevin nice to see you on here! I'll try a cleaner version that actually counts the people connected and refreshes on disconnects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround, for I don't fully understand how the component works.
I found there is a player list under the reference `NAF.entities.entities`
I made a component attached to the scene:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo',{
  init:function(){
    setTimeout(function(){   
      console.log(Object.keys(NAF.entities.entities));
      console.log(Object.keys(NAF.entities.entities)[0]);
      console.log(Object.keys(NAF.entities.entities).length);
    },5000);
  }
});
```

The first log gives me an array of the players id's.
The second one gives the id of the first element. 
The last gives me the number of the players.

You can check for the number of players on load, and depending which player loads, You set his position attribute.

```
if(NAF.. == 1) this.el.setAttribute('position',firstPos);
if(NAF.. == 2) this.el.setAttribute('position',secondPos);
if(NAF.. > 2) this.el.setAttribute('position',third);
```

Working glitch here: glitch.com/edit/#!/sudden-antler

---

Of course instead of waiting 5 seconds i should be listening to a loaded event, I'll look into it once im not so busy.

---

If anyone manages to do this properly with this component, please comment, because i tried to do the position onConnect ( too early, the other players entities are still not loaded ), tried waiting till the scene loads, but the closest i got is by dynamically creating the player when i get the number of players, after a fixed time.

Comment: Looks good, I will check it out in a few moments and tell you how it works!

Comment: @Riccardo if it works, try to figure out which event should execute the position function ( instead of the temporary 5 seconds )

Comment: I did not get it to work in my project. I got the console.logs right but I had trouble with the selection. I did some research and decided to go for the firebase solution as it seems more reasonable to work with an actual server, than to use my machine as host. But thanks a lot for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a somewhat hack solution below, but I now have figured out a clean way to figure out when connected.

```js
let connectionResolve;
let connectionPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   connectionResolve = resolve;
})
```

---

```html
<a-scene networked-scene="onConnect:connectionResolve">
```

---

```js
connectionPromise.then(() => {
  // now you can access NAF.connection.getConnectedClients() safely here
  // do stuff
})
```

You can pass a callback to onConnect of the networked-scene component. It will call that callback when you connect. By passing it a resolver for a promise, you then have a way to safely call anything and know that it will only be called if you are connected.

---

---

***Old Answer***

Note that you should be using `NAF.connection.getConnectedClients()`, not entities, as entities is anything shared between the users--it only correspondes because in a crude example the number of avatars (only shared entities) matches the number of users.

```
function onConnected(callback) {
   setTimeout(() => {
     if (NAF.connection.isConnected()) {
       callback(NAF.connection.getConnectedClients())
     }
     else onConnected(callback)

   }, 100)
}
```

(This is just to give you an idea.)

The [docs](https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe) don't seem to give a good event for this, but they do mention these functions that we can use in a less-hacky (if not quite elegant) way.